# select dropdown value is gone after on change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, dropdown

I have this code

```js
function OnSelectedIndexChange() {
  if (stsNikahWp == "2") {
    document.getElementById("kdNegaraSuami").options.length = 0;
    $("#kdNegaraSuami").attr("disabled", true);
  } else if (stsNikahWp == "1") {
    $('#kdNegaraSuami').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group mb-0">
  <label for="" class="mb-0 blue-dark-text">Status Pernikahan <font color="red">*</font></label>
  <div class="input-group border-bottom">
    <select class="form-control" id="stsNikahWp" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange()">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Kawin</option>
      <option value="2">Tidak Kawin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group mb-0">
  <label for="" class="mb-0 blue-dark-text">Kewarganegaraan Suami</label>
  <div class="input-group border-bottom">
    <select disabled class="form-control" id="kdNegaraSuami" style="border:0px;" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange()"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

this "kdNegaraSuami" drowpdown will able when I select value 1 in "stsNikahWp" dropdown. but, when I select value 2, the "kdNegaraSuami" drowpdown will become disable again.
the value in "kdNegaraSuami" drowpdown got from database.

first, I select value 1 in "stsNikahWp" dropdown. then I select value in "kdNegaraSuami" drowpdown. then I try to select value 2 in "stsNikahWp" dropdown. the value in "kdNegaraSuami" drowpdown is gone and it become disable again. I select value 1 in "stsNikahWp" dropdown, the "kdNegaraSuami" drowpdown is able but all the value in dropdown is gone. please help me. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Heing W Your code says exactly what you're describing. But please mention what you want, so we can help. like in which conditions you want it to be disabled and when not?

Comment: You need `if (stsNikahWp.value == "2")` instead; `stsNikahWp` is the `<select>` element itself.

Comment: Hi you have use `document.getElementById("kdNegaraSuami").options.length = 0;` which will remove options from second dropdown ..

Answer (score 2):

You could leave the `<option>` elements in place and set value to empty option

I modified html to pass in `this.value` from the onChange

```js
function OnSelectedIndexChange(value) {
  if (value == "2") {    
    $("#kdNegaraSuami").val('').attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('#kdNegaraSuami').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group mb-0">
  <label for="" class="mb-0 blue-dark-text">Status Pernikahan <font color="red">*</font></label>
  <div class="input-group border-bottom">
    <select class="form-control" id="stsNikahWp" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange(this.value)">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Kawin</option>
      <option value="2">Tidak Kawin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group mb-0">
  <label for="" class="mb-0 blue-dark-text">Kewarganegaraan Suami</label>
  <div class="input-group border-bottom">
    <select disabled class="form-control" id="kdNegaraSuami" style="border:0px;" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange()">
    <option value=""></option>  
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```